# Rick and Morty React + TypeScript + Redux App - Why filtering is not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, filtering, infinite-scroll

I have created an app that uses the Rick and Morty API to display a list of characters. Additionally, this app should be able to live filter the grid of results. This app also includes the `InfiniteFiltering` feature. However, I'm encountering several problems here.

Let me give you some context.

This is the `charactersSlice` file:

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { RootState } from '../../app/store';
import axios from 'axios';

export interface Character {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    species: string;
    status: string;
    origin: {
      name: string;
    };
    image: string;
}
  
interface CharactersState {
    characters: Character[];
    loading: boolean;
    error: string | null;
}
  
const initialState: CharactersState = {
    characters: [],
    loading: false,
    error: null,
};

export const fetchCharacters = createAsyncThunk<Character[], number>(
  'characters/fetchCharacters',
  async (page) => {
    const response = await axios.get(`https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/?page=${page}`);
    return response.data.results;
  }
);

const charactersSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'characters',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
      setCharacters: (state, action: PayloadAction<Character[]>) => {
        state.characters = action.payload;
      },
      setLoading: (state, action: PayloadAction<boolean>) => {
        state.loading = action.payload;
      },
      setError: (state, action: PayloadAction<string | null>) => {
        state.error = action.payload;
      },
    },
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
        builder
          .addCase(fetchCharacters.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            state.characters = action.payload;
            state.loading = false;
            state.error = null;
          })
          .addCase(fetchCharacters.pending, (state) => {
            state.loading = true;
          })
          .addCase(fetchCharacters.rejected, (state, action) => {
            state.error = action.error.message || 'An error occurred.';
            state.loading = false;
          });
      },
  });

export const { setCharacters, setLoading, setError } = charactersSlice.actions;

export const selectCharacters = (state: RootState) => state.characters.characters;
export const selectLoading = (state: RootState) => state.characters.loading;
export const selectError = (state: RootState) => state.characters.error;

export default charactersSlice.reducer;
```

This is the charactersGrid file:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchCharacters, selectCharacters } from './charactersSlice';
import { AppDispatch } from '../../app/store';
import CharacterCard from './Character';
import CharacterSearch from './CharactersSearch';
import { Character } from './charactersSlice';
import InfiniteScroll from 'react-infinite-scroll-component';

const CharacterGrid: React.FC = () => {
  const characters = useSelector(selectCharacters);
  const dispatch: AppDispatch = useDispatch();

  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState<string>('');
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [allCharacters, setAllCharacters] = useState<Character[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchCharacters(page));
  }, [dispatch, page]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Append newly loaded characters to the existing array
    setAllCharacters((prevCharacters) => [...prevCharacters, ...characters]);
  }, [characters, page]);

  const filteredCharacters = allCharacters.filter((character) =>
    character.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
  );

  const loadMore = () => {
    if (searchTerm === '') {
      setPage(page + 1);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="character-grid-container">
      <CharacterSearch searchTerm={searchTerm} onSearchChange={setSearchTerm} />
      <div className="character-grid-title-container">
        <hr />
        <h1 className="character-grid-title">Lista de personajes</h1>
        <hr />
      </div>
      <InfiniteScroll
        dataLength={filteredCharacters.length}
        next={loadMore}
        hasMore={searchTerm === ''} // Only allow loading more if searchTerm is empty
        loader={
          searchTerm === '' ? ( // Check if searchTerm is empty
            <h4 className="notification">Loading...</h4>
          ) : null // If searchTerm is not empty, don't render anything
        }
      >
        <div className="character-grid">
          {filteredCharacters.map((character) => (
            <CharacterCard key={character.id} character={character} />
          ))}
        </div>
      </InfiniteScroll>
    </div>
  );
  
};

export default CharacterGrid;
```

What is happening right now: When I scroll down, the infinite scroll is working fine. However, if I try to write something in the search field, the life filtering doesn't work. Additionally, if I clear the search field again, it loads again new more characters (that shouldn't be happening).

It should add only new characters to the `allCharacters` array if the users scrolls. More over, if the search field some value, it shouldn't load more characters and neither if it is empty again.

The goal is to filter the current characters available in the `allCharacters` array.

Apparently, the filter only works if I use `characters.filter` instead of `allCharacters.filter` in this code:

```
const filteredCharacters = allCharacters.filter((character) =>
    character.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
  );
```

Please, I need help to fix it.

I tried different approaches but it doesn't work.

The app should be able to load more character only when it scrolls and the search field is empty.

UPDATE TO THE ANSWER:

thank you so much for your advice.

After posting the previous code, I updated the charactersGrid with some code in order to avoid key repetition and generate random ids.

Could you help me to apply the previous solution to this updated code?

```js
// Import necessary dependencies and components from external files
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchCharacters, selectCharacters, selectError } from './charactersSlice';
import { AppDispatch } from '../../app/store';
import CharacterCard from './Character';
import CharacterSearch from './CharactersSearch';
import { Character } from './charactersSlice';
import InfiniteScroll from 'react-infinite-scroll-component';

// Define a functional React component called CharacterGrid
const CharacterGrid: React.FC = () => {
    // Retrieve characters and error from the Redux store
    const characters = useSelector(selectCharacters);
    const error = useSelector(selectError);
    const dispatch: AppDispatch = useDispatch();

    // Define and initialize state variables for search, pagination, and character data
    const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState<string>('');
    const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
    const [allCharacters, setAllCharacters] = useState<Character[]>([]);

    // Use the useEffect hook to fetch characters when the page or store changes
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(fetchCharacters(page));
    }, [dispatch, page]);

    // Use another useEffect to append newly loaded characters to the existing character data
    useEffect(() => {
        // Create a set of character IDs to check for duplicates
        const existingCharacterIds = allCharacters.map((character) => character.id);
        const newCharacters = characters.filter(
        (character) => !existingCharacterIds.includes(character.id)
        );

        // Append newly loaded characters to the existing array
        setAllCharacters((prevCharacters) => [...prevCharacters, ...newCharacters]);
    }, [characters, allCharacters, page]);

    // Filter characters based on the search term, and assign random keys to each character
    const filteredCharacters = allCharacters.filter((character) =>
        character.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
    );

    // Add a random key to the character
    const filteredCharactersWithRandomKeys = filteredCharacters.map((character) => {
        const randomKey = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
        return { ...character, randomKey };
    });

    // Function to load more characters when the InfiniteScroll component triggers it
    const loadMore = () => {
        if (searchTerm === '') {
        setPage(page + 1);
        }
    };

    // Render the component's JSX structure
    return (
        <div id="character-grid-container" className="character-grid-container">
        {/* Display the character search input component */}
        <CharacterSearch searchTerm={searchTerm} onSearchChange={setSearchTerm} />
        <div className="character-grid-title-container">
            <hr />
            <h1 className="character-grid-title">Lista de personajes</h1>
            <hr />
        </div>
        {/* Implement the InfiniteScroll component for lazy loading */}
        <InfiniteScroll
            dataLength={filteredCharactersWithRandomKeys.length}
            next={loadMore}
            hasMore={searchTerm === ''} // Only allow loading more if searchTerm is empty
            loader={
            searchTerm === '' ? ( // Check if searchTerm is empty
                error ? ( // If there's an error, display the error message
                <h4 className="notification error">{error}</h4>
                ) : (
                <h4 className="notification">Loading...</h4>
                )
            ) : null // If searchTerm is not empty, don't render anything
            }
        >
            {filteredCharactersWithRandomKeys.length === 0 ? (
            <h4 className="notification">No se ha encontrado ningún personaje...</h4>
            ) : (
            <div className="character-grid">
                {/* Map and render the CharacterCard component for each character */}
                {filteredCharactersWithRandomKeys.map((character) => (
                <CharacterCard key={character.randomKey} character={character} />
                ))}
            </div>
            )}
        </InfiniteScroll>
        </div>
    );
};

// Export the CharacterGrid component as the default export
export default CharacterGrid;
```

Answer (score 0):

- Don't duplicate the Redux state into local state, append all new data to the `characters` array in the Redux state.
- The `useEffect` hook initiates duplicate calls for the same page, creating duplicates in the `allCharacters` array. You can just compute `filteredCharacters` directly from the selected `characters` state from the store and the local `searchTerm` filter state value.

character.slice

```js
const charactersSlice = createSlice({
  name: "characters",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    ...
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(fetchCharacters.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.characters.push(...action.payload); // <-- append characters here
        state.loading = false;
        state.error = null;
      })
      .addCase(fetchCharacters.pending, (state) => {
        state.loading = true;
      })
      .addCase(fetchCharacters.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.error = action.error.message || "An error occurred.";
        state.loading = false;
      });
  }
});
```

CharacterGrid

```
const CharacterGrid = () => {
  const characters = useSelector(selectCharacters);
  const dispatch: AppDispatch = useDispatch();

  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState<string>("");
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchCharacters(page));
  }, [dispatch, page]);

  const filteredCharacters = characters.filter((character) =>
    character.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
  );

  const loadMore = () => {
    if (searchTerm === "") {
      setPage(page + 1);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="character-grid-container">
      <CharacterSearch searchTerm={searchTerm} onSearchChange={setSearchTerm} />
      <div className="character-grid-title-container">
        <hr />
        <h1 className="character-grid-title">Lista de personajes</h1>
        <hr />
      </div>
      <InfiniteScroll
        dataLength={filteredCharacters.length}
        next={loadMore}
        hasMore={searchTerm === ""} // Only allow loading more if searchTerm is empty
        loader={
          searchTerm === "" ? ( // Check if searchTerm is empty
            <h4 className="notification">Loading...</h4>
          ) : null // If searchTerm is not empty, don't render anything
        }
      >
        <div className="character-grid">
          {filteredCharacters.map((character) => (
            <CharacterCard key={character.id} character={character} />
          ))}
        </div>
      </InfiniteScroll>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit rick-and-morty-react-typescript-redux-app-why-filtering-is-not-working]

### Things to note/Suggestions

- The `useEffect` hook runs more often in development builds within the `React.StrictMode` component. `StrictMode` is commented out in sandbox so duplicate API calls are not made.
- Instead of always pushing whatever is fetched into the `characters` array, keep the data in a Map or Set (*to not allow duplicates in data*) and use the `selectCharacters` to convert state to the array for the UI.
- You are already using Redux-Toolkit, integrate Redux-Toolkit Query and convert the Thunks to endpoints and let RTKQ handle de-duplicating API calls and caching results.